# i am creating exam portal in spring boot but i am stucked at one error which is as follows

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

here following is the code please give me the proper solution which will really work i have tried to run it multiple times but it is not working

```
import com.exam.model.user;
import com.exam.model.userRole;
import com.exam.repo.RoleRepository;
import com.exam.repo.UserRepository;
import com.exam.service.UserService;
import org.apache.catalina.Store;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Set;

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Override
    public user createUser(user user, Set<userRole> userRoles) throws Exception {

      user local = this.userRepository.findByUserName(user.getUsername());
      if(local!=null)
      {
          System.out.println("User already exists !!!");
          throw new Exception("user already present...");
      }
      else
      {
          //creating user
          for(userRole ur:userRoles)
          {
              roleRepository.save(ur.getRole());//saving roles from userRole list
          }

          user.getUserRoles().addAll(userRoles);
          local =this.userRepository.save(user);
      }
        return user;
    }
}
```

also the code of two repositories which i have created is as follows
user reposetory

```
import com.exam.model.user;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<user,Long>
{

    public user findByUserName(String username);
}
```

"role repository"

````
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import com.exam.model.role;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<role,Long> {



}```

and the error are ass follows 

```Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-14 01:26:48.542 ERROR 14372 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
````

full stack trace

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-03-14 01:26:48.542 ERROR 14372 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository' defined in com.exam.repo.UserRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.exam.model.user com.exam.repo.UserRepository.findByUserName(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.exam.model.user com.exam.repo.UserRepository.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'userName' found for type 'user'; Did you mean 'username'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.exam.model.user com.exam.repo.UserRepository.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'userName' found for type 'user'; Did you mean 'username'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:936) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.9.jar:2.7.9]
    at com.exam.ExamserverApplication.main(ExamserverApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract com.exam.model.user com.exam.repo.UserRepository.findByUserName(java.lang.String); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.exam.model.user com.exam.repo.UserRepository.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'userName' found for type 'user'; Did you mean 'username'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.exam.model.user com.exam.repo.UserRepository.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'userName' found for type 'user'; Did you mean 'username'
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:107) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1061) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1845) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:365) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:231) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:329) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar:5.3.25]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract com.exam.model.user com.exam.repo.UserRepository.findByUserName(java.lang.String)! No property 'userName' found for type 'user'; Did you mean 'username'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:259) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:103) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'userName' found for type 'user'; Did you mean 'username'
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:91) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:438) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:414) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:367) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:349) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:332) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:385) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.8.jar:2.7.8]
    ... 42 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

just give me the proper solution so i can move further in my project

Comment: `No property 'userName' found for type 'user'; Did you mean 'username'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the JPA Repository method must match the name of the fields/columns in the Entity.

- `name` -> `findByName(...)`
- `userName` -> `findByUserName(...)`
- `username` -> `findByUsername(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Change the method name findByUserName to findByUsername